# Intersection of infinite number of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Assume I have infinite number of sets such as $\left[1,\infty\right),\left[2,\infty\right),\left[3,\infty\right),...$.Any number in such set is natural.

What is intersection of them: $S = \left[1,\infty\right)\cap\left[2,\infty\right)\cap\left[3,\infty\right),...$? How does it look like?

Comment: Just checking, when you write $\{1,\infty\}$, do you mean a set of two elements, one of which is the symbol $\infty$, or do you mean the infinite set $\{1,2,3,4,\dots\}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Am I correct in assuming your notation of $\{k, \infty\}$ means $\{k, k+1, k+2, .........\}$?

Well,

Question 1: what elements do all the sets have in common?

Question 2: are there any elements that are in all sets?

Question 3: Take a natural number, $k$,  Which sets is that in?  And which sets is it not in?

Answer:

> The is no element in common with all the sets.  So the intersection is the empty set.

Comment: Well, cool. But every set is a subset of previous (except first). I think we should intoduce mystery number natural S.

Comment: True.  But that doesn't mean there is any subset that is a subset of all of them (except the emptyset) or that there is any "smallest" or last set. (except maybe the emptyset).

Comment: " I think we should intoduce mystery number natural S. "  No.  I *really* don't think we should.  It couldn't have any value.  It isn't finite and therefore not natural, and there is no reason for it to exist.

Comment: Your answer is right. But I believe that it exists. It's just out of our mind.

Comment: "But I believe that it exists. It's just out of our mind."  You and every other sophist when they first learn mathematics.  Trust me.  The sooner you get over this idea the better off you will be.  These ghost particles only appear compelling because it is difficult to forego the instincts we've developed by dealing our entire lives with finite examples.  But our assumptions are *all* wrong when it comes to infinite quantities. And there is *no* reason to think they are right except they *seem* right.  And that is not an acceptable reason.

Comment: I google it and found such thing as hyperreal number. Check it out [link] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperreal_number). Pretty looks like my mystery number S.

Comment: Hyperreal numbers are a different number system and are *not* natural numbers.  If your sets each included all the natural numbers *as well as* the hyperreal $\omega$ then the intersection is $\{\omega\}$.  But this has nothing to do with the hyperreal $\omega$.  The same would be true if you included the sets to be $\{k, k+1, k+2,....... \text{babar the elephant}\}$.  Then the intersection would be $\{\text{babar the elephant}\}$.  But as your sets contain *only* natural numbers the intersection is the empty set as there are no natural numbers that are equal or larger to all natural numbers.

Comment: You are looking for a *natural* number, $S$ so that for all natural numbers $n$, $n \le S$.  No such *natural* number exists.  And no such *real* number exists.  To have such a number $S$ so that $n \le S$ for all natural numbers you need a hyperreal infinite value $\infty$ or $\omega$.  But $\omega$ is neither real *nor* natural.  And it is *not* in the set $\{1,2,3,4.....\}$ unless you specify that your set is $\{1,2,3,..... \omega\}$ but that is a completely different set.  The difference between $\omega$ and your mystery $S$ is ... to be continued....

Comment: The difference between $\omega$ and your mystery $S$ is you are trying to will $S$ into existence by believing that the intersection of nesting sets can't be empty. They can and often are. Consider $A_0=(0,1)$ and $A_1=(0,\frac 13)\cup (\frac 23, \frac 13)$  and $A_2 = (0,\frac 19)\cup (\frac 29,\frac 13)\cup (\frac 23, \frac 79)\cup (\frac 89, 1)$ etc. (the cantor set but with *open* intervals).  There are *no* values that are in *all* of those Sets. So the intersection is empty.  If you consider hyperreals there will be an infinite number of necessary hyperreals all different than your $S$.

Comment: Thanks for such informative answer.